# Count choices in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model like:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    YES_NO_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'Yes'),
        (False, 'No'),
    )
    satisfaction = models.BooleanField(choices=YES_NO_CHOICES, default=True)
    register = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to get responses from this questionnaire grouped by months and count "yes" and "no" responses.

Example, I have responses like this:

```
{
    '2015-11-29': {True: 1, False: 2},
    '2015-11-30': {True: 3, False: 1},
    '2015-12-01': {True: 5, False: 2},
    '2015-12-05': {True: 3, False: 6}
}
```

I need a django queryset to do something like:

```
{
    {'2015-11-01': {True: 4, False: 3},
    {'2015-12-01': {True: 8, False: 8}
}
```

The date is not important, in template I'll just use the month value (01, 02, 03, ..., 11, 12).

I'm searching for a pythonic way to do this, preferably with queryset in django, not dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907240/django-monthly-quartarly-grouping-of-datefield-data

Comment: Do you want to group only by month, or by month and year? In other words: do you want the number of 'yes' answers in December 2015, or in December (any year)?

Comment: By the way, Django has no bultin support for this kind of stuff. You are forced to use SQL. What is your database backend?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini what about [Aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)?

Comment: @vyscond: you can use them to count, but you have to filter based on month first

Comment: Ops, sorry. You do not have to filter by month (otherwise you would have to do 12 queries, even more if you need the year). You have to *group* by month.

Comment: I'd check to see if Conditional Sums combined with some annotated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini month/year, sorry, I forgot to mention this. Basically, I I'll make a chart with this data using column chart to represent yes/no in each month in a dates range.
I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral: you can do that, but you'd need a `Case` for every month/year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we need to extract the month and year values for use in our query. We do this by using `extra()`. Django has no builtin support for that, unfortunately.

Then, we can group by year and month using `values()`.

Finally, we can aggregate on the yes/no answers by using `annotate()` and conditional expressions:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Sum, When

conn = connections[Questionnaire.objects.db]

Questionnaire.objects.extra(
    select={
        'year': conn.ops.date_trunc_sql('year', 'register'),
        'month': conn.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'register'),
    }).values(
        'year', 'month'
    ).annotate(
        yes_count=Sum(
            Case(When(satisfaction=True, then=1),
                 output_field=IntegerField()),
        ),
        no_count=Sum(
            Case(When(satisfaction=False, then=1),
                 output_field=IntegerField()),
        )
    )
```

You might also want to `order_by('year', 'month')`, but that is not necessary for the code to work.

The result will be a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'year': '2015-01-01', 'month': '2015-11-01', 'yes_count': 201, 'no_count': 422},
 {'year': '2015-01-01', 'month': '2015-12-01', 'yes_count': 324, 'no_count': 223},
 ...]
```

As you can see, `year` and `month` are not numeric, but are strings. However you can easily extract the year and the month by splitting:

```
year = int(item['year'].split('-')[0])
month = int(item['month'].split('-')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Choices to be

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    YES_NO_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Yes'),
        (0, 'No'),
    )
    satisfaction = models.SmallPoistiveIntegerField(choices=YES_NO_CHOICES, default=1)
    register = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then

```
result = Questionnaire.objects.extra(
     select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM register)",
             'month': "EXTRACT(month FROM register)",
             'yes': "satisfaction = 1",
             'no': "satisfaction = 0",
            }).annotate(yes_count=models.Sum("yes"),
                        no_count=models.Sum("no")).order_by("year", "month").values("yes_count", "no_count", "month", "year")
for row in result:
    print("yes {yes_count}, no {no_count}".format(**row))
    print("date {year}-{month}-01".format(**row))
```

Edit, I see you have to use extra anyway so I might as well include yes and no columns and have a the code look a bit cleaner

Comment: this is not grouping by month

Answer (score 0):

for those who still looking for a better approach :

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
Questionnaire.object.annotate(month=TruncMonth('register'))values(month).annotate(
satisfaction_true=Count('id',filter=Q(satisfaction=True),satisfaction_false=Count('id',filter=Q(satisfaction=False))
```